# Restricting URL so that only web application can access it (firebase + google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest, firebase

I was wondering if it was possible to restrict a URL so that only your web application can query it.

I want to store a list of used usernames so that when a user signs up, I can check if the username they want to use is unique.

I am storing my usernames both in a FIREBASE and Google App Engine data store.

I was wondering if it was possible to restrict the URL that my server queries (e.g. /usernames) so that ONLY my server can query it. That is, if someone goes to the URL usernames, they'll just be redirected back to the home page or something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Secure the url so that it requires authorization to access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make sure only my own website (clientside code) can talk to Firebase backend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890330/how-to-make-sure-only-my-own-website-clientside-code-can-talk-to-firebase-back)